# Can't upgrade PHP 5.5.32 to PHP 7.x on CentOS 7

Tags: centos7, php7

recently I've got a VPS with CentOS 7 installed and some pre-installed packages such as LAMP stack. I removed httpd and installed nginx successfully but I have not been able to remove/update PHP from 5.5.32 to 7.x.

I tried using the Remi Repo using [their wizard](http://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/) with no success, after following the steps I get the very same php version:

```
# php --version PHP
5.5.32 (cli) (built: Feb 10 2016 14:58:51)  Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
```

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Definitively not enough information. Post command (from the Wizard) and thier output.

Comment: Start with a fresh installation of CentOS, _without_ a bunch of junk pre-installed.